# Too much space between red flag icon and comment

Tags: bug, comments, comment-flags

I just flagged a comment as not constructive. I mistakenly refreshed the page. Here is what I saw:

[image]

There's too much gap between the flag icon, and the text. Before refreshing, they text and icon were together, and looked like (note: different comment):

[image]

I could even reproduce this with different comments. Although, on each comment this didn't happen. Here is a comment with which I could repro

[image]

[image]

As I can repro (not every time), this looks like a bug.

Could the SO team look into this?

I work on Chrome 41 on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

---

Repro steps:

This doesn't happen on every comment. But if you're in luck, and you think that the comment will repro, do this:

- Flag the comment.
- Hover over the comment. You will see a red icon.
- Refresh the page.
- Again hover over the comment.

If you're in luck, you'll see a huge gap between the text of the comment, and the red flag icon. Refreshing the page is very important in reproducing it.

Comment: I saw that also with FF Dev Edition (48.0a2) on Linux Mint, couldn't come up with decent repro steps. Next time it happens I'll make sure to look at the code and check what's happening.

Comment: I can repro on Chrome 50 Win10.

Comment: I remember I reproduced it also with Firefox 46, Win 10 also.